# Can I use GnuPG connect to PGP public key servers?

Tags: encryption, gnupg, public-key

I use gpg 1.4.19 on Windows.

Can I communicate with the server directly from the command line?
I tried this many things, but nothing worked:

Tried:

```
>gpg --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu --search-keys vivarto@gmail.com
```

And got this

```
gpg: searching for "vivarto@gmail.com" from hkp server pgp.mit.edu
gpg: system error while calling external program: No such file or directory
gpg: WARNING: unable to remove tempfile (out) `C:\Users\Vivarto\AppData\Local\Temp\gpg-5E2480\tempout.txt': No such file or directory
gpg: no handler for keyserver scheme `hkp'
gpg: keyserver search failed: keyserver error
```

Then I tried:

```
>gpg hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --search-keys vivarto
```

And got this:

```
usage: gpg [options] [filename]
```

I was able to connect to MIC server using email.
I don't know how to do that with the *pool.sks-keyservers.net* server.

Would greatly appreciate any help.
Thank you.
Vivarto

Answer (score 1):

I know this works on Linux...

From the "`system error while calling external program: No such file or directory`" error it looks like your gpg isn't fully installed or configured. Searching for that error finds this potentially helpful line:

> There should be a program named gpgkeys_hkp.exe in the same directory as gpg.exe

Where's your `gpgkeys`-anything .exe file?

Maybe you need to reinstall or do a full install of gpg

Comment: Thank you, indeed I did not have the gpgkeys files.
Now I added them.
I can get the info from the MIT server, but this one
**>gpg hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --search-keys vivarto**
Is still not working.

Here are my executable:

12/09/2015  06:26 PM           965,120 gpg.exe
02/27/2015  10:48 AM            72,704 gpgkeys_finger.exe
02/27/2015  10:48 AM            86,528 gpgkeys_hkp.exe
02/27/2015  10:48 AM            43,008 gpgkeys_ldap.exe

Anyway, this is already a huge improvement that I can communicate with MIT key server.
Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for the atrocious formatting. 
Have no idea how to make it look nice.

Comment: Formatting in comments is *very* limited, pretty much bold, italic, code & links IIRC. The help has more, well... help :-)  Maybe you're missing an option to tell gpg to use a different server? gpg on linux uses `--keyserver [server]` so try it in front of the server. And if the answer works (or is just helpful) please do select/check-mark it (&/or upvote - the up arrow to the left), thanks

Comment: Thank you this works:

_gpg *--keyserver* hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --search-keys vivarto@gmail.com_

I have already upvoted last time, and I cannot do it again.